# Python: Checking a list with regex, filling in blanks

Tags: python, regex, list, missing-data

I've tried to find ways to do this and searched online here, but cannot find examples to help me figure this out.

I'm reading in rows from a large csv and changing each row to a list.  The problem is that the data source isn't very clean.  It has empty strings or bad data sometimes, and I need to fill in default values when that happens.  For example:

```
list_ex1 = ['apple','9','','2012-03-05','455.6']
list_ex2 = ['pear','0','45','wrong_entry','565.11']
```

Here, list_ex1 has a blank third entry and list_ex2 has erroneous data where a date should be.  To be clear, I can create a regex that limits what each of the five entries should be:

```
reg_ex_check = ['[A-Za-z]+','[0-9]','[0-9]','[0-9]{4}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]','[0-9.]+']
```

That is:

- 1st entry: A string, no numbers
- 2nd entry: Exactly one digit between 0 and 9
- 3rd entry: Exactly one digit as well.
- 4th entry: Date in standard format (allowing any four digit ints for year)
- 5th entry: Float

If an entry is blank OR does not match the regular expression, then it should be filled in/replaced with the following defaults:

```
default_fill = ['empty','0','0','2000-01-01','0']
```

I'm not sure how the best way to go about this is.  I think I could write a complicated loop, but it doesn't feel very 'pythonic' to me to do such things.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` and a conditional expression in a list comprehension:

```
[x if re.match(r,x) else d for x,r,d in zip(list_ex2,reg_ex_check,default_fill)]
Out[14]: ['pear', '0', '45', '2000-01-01', '565.11']
```

You don't really need to explicitly check for blank strings since your various regexen (plural of regex) will all fail on blank strings.

Other note: you probably still want to add an anchor for the end of your string to each regex.  Using `re.match` ensures that it tries to match from the start, but still provides no guarantee that there is not illegal stuff *after* your match.  Consider:

```
['pear and a pear tree', '0blah', '4 4 4', '2000-01-0000', '192.168.0.bananas']
```

The above entire list is "acceptable" if you don't add a `$` anchor to the end of each regex :-)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on the blank strings, I should have thought of that.  Plus for regexen.

Comment: @nfmcclure no problem.  See my edit, you should probably consider adding an extra end-of-string anchor to all your regex.

Comment: you may want to compile your regexp list for efficiency! since it is used many times in multiple loops.

Comment: @caesarsol the `re` module caches the last 100 compiled regex so that isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
map(lambda(x,y,z): re.search(y,x) and x or z, zip(list_ex1, reg_ex_check, default_fill))
```